# ../main: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_highgui.so.4.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, shared-libraries

I am trying to load the main library which is present at same path of which environment variable is set 
"$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" :/home/.../opencv/build/lib over which the library is present 
I have even tried setting up the varible to usr/../lib where it was previously pointing

Comment: Trying using the 'ldd' command on the executable.  It should indicate if the library is found or not.  If not found then make sure it is really on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH,  without relative address is best.  I note three dots in your example path which wont work so maybe that is the whole issue.  Also make sure the library is the write architecture 32/64-bit with the 'file' command

Comment: OpenCV 4.0 hasn't been released yet. Are you sure you're experienced enough to work with an in-development build of a library undergoing a major version change? If not, it may be wiser to stick with a stable release, such as the [latest 3.4.3](https://opencv.org/releases.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that you set the environment variable by running `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/lib`. The dollar symbol is used when quote the variable, not in setting.